# What is the maximum number of $2$-inch by $2$-inch by $2$-inch cubes

Tags: geometry

> What is the maximum number of $2$-inch by $2$-inch by $2$-inch cubes that can be placed in a box that measures $7$-inches by $8$-inches by $9$-inches?

I thought the answer would be $\dfrac{504}{8} = 63$, but that is the maximum. Some may not fit. How do I find how many do?

Comment: Hint: Your answer would have been correct if the question were - "how many 2x2x2 cubes could be melted and poured into the 7x8x9 box?"

Comment: Hint: If you build a cuboid out of $2"\times2"\times2"$ cubes, what property does the cuboid have?

Comment: You can trivially pack $3\times 4 \times 4 = 48$ cubes into the box. if the cubes are axis-aligned and the coordinates of its vertices (wrt the box, in units of  inches) are integers, this is also the maximum you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: assume the $7\times8$ face is on the ground. Then you may line up $4$ of the cubes perfectly along the $8$ inch side, and you can fit $3$ of these rows in total along the base, and no more. Now the height of the box is $9$ inches. How many cubes high can you go then?

Comment: 3 across, 4 forward, and 4 up for a total of $48$

Comment: This is fine if the cubes must be aligned with the sides of the big box, but there might be a better packing